# How to select events within current week using wp_query

Tags: wp-query, events

I'm trying to create an events page that lists events (custom post type) within the week. I'm having trouble properly selecting only the posts that have a 'start_date' that falls in the current week.

Here is my code:

```
    $day = date('w');
    $week_start = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('-'. $day . ' days'));
    $week_end = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('+' . (6 - $day) . ' days'));

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'hcc_events',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'meta_key' => 'start_date',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'start_date',
                'value' => $week_start,
                'compare' => '>=',
                'type' => 'DATE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'start_date',
                'value' => $week_end,
                'compare' => '<=',
                'type' => 'DATE'
            )
        )
    );
```

Right now nothing is output at all. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Dates have to be stored as time stamps or in the format yyyy-mm-dd to query on them

Comment: Just checking, sometimes it is the silliest errors that catch us.  please show the code where you pass the args to the query function and how you deal with the result.     Also might be good to check the format of the data in the database ? As Milo pointed out if you want to do < and > querying, store the dates with the YYYY first.

Comment: Changing the datetimes to the format of 'Y-m-d' worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the date format to Y-m-d on ACF and in my code was what fixed everything!

Answer (score 1):

This is simple way provided by wordpress:

```
$loop = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
        'posts_per_page' => 7,
        'meta_key' => 'meta_key',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'date_query' => array(
            'date_query' => array(
                array(
                    'year' => date('Y'),
                    'week' => date('W'),
                ),
            ),
        ),

    )
);
```